# React Typescript: Extract table to component and pass additional props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to create custom components for `table`, `td`, `tr` etc in order to style them in one place. How do I specify the props for this?
The following code is my attempt to achieve this but I get a lot of errors saying that the props are not assignable to the type.

```
import React, { ReactNode, FC } from "react";

interface Props {
  children: ReactNode;
}

const Table: FC<Props & HTMLTableElement> = ({ children, ...rest }) => (
  <table {...rest} className="min-w-full divide-y divide-gray-300">
    {children}
  </table>
);

export default Table;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `FC<Props & HTMLTableElement>` with:

```
const Table: FC<
  Props &
    React.DetailedHTMLProps<
      React.TableHTMLAttributes<HTMLTableElement>,
      HTMLTableElement
    >
> = ({ children, ...rest }) => (
  <table {...rest} className="min-w-full divide-y divide-gray-300">
    {children}
  </table>
);
```

Now you should be able to pass all accepted props of `<table />`.